# how to add python code in href attribute in html tag

Tags: python, html, django

I am new to python, I have a code that iterates the list in HTML using python

```
   {% for e in news %}
      <h5 class="title"> {{ e.title }}</h5>
      <a href="{% e.url %}"> url </a>
   {% endfor %}
```

getting template syntax error in href tag. Please let me know if you know the solution.

Comment: What kind of template is this? Django?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the url tag to

```
href="{{ e.url }}"
```

The `"{% ... %}"` is used for python statement instead of expression, which we shall use `"{{ ... }}"`.

it will work

```
{% for e in news %}
  <h5 class="title"> {{ e.title }}</h5>
  <a href="{{ e.url }}"> url </a>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: it worked ... thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are using Django template url, which should be like,
`{% url 'name' *args if you have %}`

As there is no other data in your question, so i recommend reading [Django Official Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/intro/tutorial03/) and add accordingly.